# Amazon S3 custom domain per bucket or folder

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We will have many (thousands) vendors we can host their website using their custom domain.

I know the max of buckets are 100.

Is there anyway we can assign the custom domain to S3 folder not bucket?
Can we do this (assigning custom domain) via API?

If I can use CloudFront, that would be great.

If I can't do on S3, are there any other CDN hosting available?

Comment: You can request a service limit increase over the 100 limit.

Answer (score 0):

You should not (and cannot) use a domain per folder. From a should not perspective, it increases the risk of resource leak (I.e., a user who has access to one folder accidentally gets access to a separate folder). From a cannot perspective, here is AWS's documentation around setting up an origin for cloudfront: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html#concept_S3Origin. Note that it doesn't allow you to use slashes in the bucket path, which would be required to use a specific folder.

You can request additional s3 buckets per account in your service limits by following these instructions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html

You can also use additional accounts to store extra buckets if absolutely needed.

Comment: I would like to create the service users can create the HTML/CSS website and publish to S3 with custom domain. It could be more than 10,000. I don't think AWS allows me to create many buckets.

Comment: AWS doesn't publish the max service limits, so I don't know what they are. You can't use sub-folders though (and especially if people are pushing files into the buckets, you really don't want that from a security risk perspective). I'd pursue understanding the max limits from AWS first.